# Find the path of the file loading base class defining variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following sample code:

```
$ cat f1.py
class classA(object):
    var1 = "something"

$ cat f2.py
from f1 import classA
class classB(classA):
    pass

$ cat loader.py
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
from f2 import classB

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for cl in classB.__mro__:
        print cl.__module__

$ ./loader.py
f2
f1
__builtin__
```

I would like to print the absolute or relative path of the file(s) where  classB (f2.py) and classA (f1.py) are defined. Specifically, I would like to know the file of the class that actually defines `var1`. If I have a real module, then I get e.g. `mymodule.f1` which it looks like I have to search in `sys.path` to actually find it on disk.

Is there an easier way? Why don't classes (i.e. non-instances) have a `__file__` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is:

```
sys.modules[__module__].__file__
```

We modify loader.py above to say:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for cl in classB.__mro__:
        print sys.modules[cl.__module__].__file__

$ ./loader.py
/Users/virgilg/Code/testing/python/f2.pyc
/Users/virgilg/Code/testing/python/f1.pyc
```

To answer the question "which file/class defines `var1`?", we can do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    oldCl = None
    for cl in classB.__mro__:
        if not hasattr(cl, 'var1'):
            break
        oldCl = cl


    print sys.modules[oldCl.__module__].__file__

$ ./loader.py
/Users/virgilg/Code/testing/python/f1.pyc
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html?highlight=getfile#inspect.getfile) module.

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(ClassA.__class__)
inspect.getfile(ClassB.__class__)
```

Comment: Hmm, per the inspect docs, I somehow get a TypeError, since `classB` is apparently a built-in:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    inspect.getfile(classB.__class__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 408, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__builtin__' (built-in)> is a built-in class`